# Javascript full date string to Boolean is true although its invalid

Tags: javascript, date, iso8601

The Day Month and Years are working great
The Hours Mintues Szzs are not.. 
Placing invalid data on the string will still be true

"22/4/2015T25:18:32.1234.Z" or
"22/4/2015T11:61:32.1234.Z"

I tired use regular expressions

```js
  function validateDateFormat(input) {    
    var dateTest = input.split(/[\.\-\/]/); // 
    var yyyy = parseInt(dateTest[2],10);
    var mm   = parseInt(dateTest[1],10);
    var dd   = parseInt(dateTest[0],10);
    
    var date = new Date(yyyy,mm-1,dd,0,0,0,0);
    return mm === (date.getMonth()+1) && dd === date.getDate()  && yyyy === date.getFullYear();
  }
  alert(validateDateFormat("22/4/2015T230:18:32.1234.Z")) //true not valid
```

I expect the output of validateDateFormat("22/4/2015T230:18:32.1234.Z") to be false

Comment: Well, you only check the date, month, and year portions. And they are valid. You never check the hour

Comment: Would be nice if the input date strings would actually be ISO8601, so that using `new Date( dateStr );` would return invalid date if the input string cannot be parsed correctly.